# SMTP connect() failed error after 70 successful sends

Tags: phpmailer

A number of people had shown similar question, using **phpmailer** with g-mail. This problem is slightly different and may need a different answer.

The phpmailer code is fairly standard (below). I have a loop that goes through some data in the table and builds customised messages for recipients, sending a message for each row in the table. When the message is sent, it successfully completes about 75 out of some 100 recipients, and for the last 25, it reports the **SMTP connect() failed** error. This doesn't happen every time, and occasionally, the script goes through the loop without errors.

```
<?php
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPsecure = "ssl";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;  // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "xx"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "xx"; // SMTP account password 
$mail->SetFrom("xx@gmail.com");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
$mail->Subject = $msgsubject;
$mail->AltBody = "Invitation";
  do {
    $membername = $row_musicians['name'];
    $membernumber = $row_musicians['number'];
    $emailaddress = $row_musicians['email'];
    $rhdate = $row_musicians['rhdate'];

$mail->clearAttachments();
$mail->Body = 'Dear '.$membername.',
  <p>'.$maintext.'</p>
  ';
// some more text using custom variables from database
// closing part of the message
$mail->Body .= '<p>'.nl2br($closing, false).'</p>
</body>
</html>';
 $mail->AddAddress($emailaddress, $membername); // sending each message
  sleep(1); // wait one second between sends, to avoid spam filters
 echo '<br />
 Recipient: '.$membername.' ('.$emailaddress.') -- ';   
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: <div style='color:#009999'>" . $mail->ErrorInfo."        </div>";
        } else {
              echo "Message sent!";
}
  $mail->ClearAddresses();
    } while ($row_musicians = mysql_fetch_assoc($musicians));
mysql_free_result($musicians);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend basing your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

You're doing most things right - initialising PHPMailer first and setting properties that are common to all messages, but one key thing is missing:

```
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
```

Without this it means that it closes and reopens a connection for every message, and you're mostly likely running into connection rate limits.

you're also using the combination of `Port= 587` and `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` which will generally not work; switch to `Port = 465`.

I'd also recommend against the `do/while` loop - it will fail if your database query fails to find anything because it's bottom-tested and thus will always run once, even if there is no data. Use a `while` or `foreach` loop instead.

The mailing list example does all of these things already.

Final thing - if this is all your code, it looks like you're running an old version of PHPMailer, so get the latest.

Comment: All great advice, thanks for all that!
I will have to test the ports, depending on how g-mail likes them.
Also, the do/while is an excellent advice. Although my code is very unlikely to ever get no data, it is a smart idea to change it to foreach, just in case.

It may be an older PHPMailer, I'll get a new one (this one has been running for years now).

Thanks again! I'll test all and mark the answer once all checks out!